# How to not view a bar in histogram ? using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, histogram

I have drawn a histogram of a variable **I** using the function **hist** available in Matlab R2012b. 
`hist(I(:),100);` 
I have got the following result, it is a histogram : 
[image]

The problem is as follow: I don't care about the values on **Zero** following X-axis. I would like to draw a histogram without putting focus on the huge value of zeros.

I found this solution :

```
[counts,centers] = hist(I(:));
[~,i] = max(counts);
counts(i)= 0;
bar(centers,counts);
```

But it seems not good one !

Is there a way to specify **bins** interval without zero !? is there a way, using code, to zoom in so that I can recognize clearly the other bars ?

The documentation of the function hist is available [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).

Any suggestion is a welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about zeros, don't pass them to `hist`:

```
hist(I(I~=0),100)
```

Comment: Can you explain more what "I~=0" mean ? how do we call what you have done ? is there a help page on matlab dedicated to such tips ? ;)

Comment: do I do this 'I=I(:)' before or no need for that ?

Comment: `I~=0` is a logical index which is true for all nonzero values. `I(I~=0)` uses this logical index to select all nonzero values of `I`.